# Adding pictures from the Web to a Powerpoint slide in VBA (MacOS)

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I'm comfortably using VBA to iterate through a list of content in an Excel spreadsheet and creating slides in a separate Powerpoint file. That bit works.

However I can't seem to add pictures to the Powerpoint presentation. I've tried:

- **Using [Shapes.AddPicture](http://mac2.microsoft.com/vb/1033/PowerPoint/html/ppmthAddPicture.htm) with an URL to the image.** A few mention this should work; apparently it broke in some Office version (see http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/powerpoint-2007-vba-addpicture-web-image-problem-t3171074.html);
- **Using Shapes.AddPicture with the path to a file.** This *should* work, but:

`Dim pic`
`Set pic = activeSlide.Shapes.AddPicture("/Users/Pedro/My_Picture.png", False, True, 10, 10)`

...fails with a Runtime Error 5 (invalid procedure call or argument).
 Please note I'm on **Mac OS X, Office 2011**.

I've also tried setting the Fill of an object via UserPicture() to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Answer (score 2):

This works on Windows versions of PPT but fails in Mac 2011:

```
Sub thing()
Dim oPic As Shape
Set oPic = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes.AddPicture("http://www.somesite.xxx/directory/filename.jpg", False, True, 0, 0, -1, -1)
End Sub
```

Quite a few things that should work (and do in the Win versions) fail in Mac PPT, unfortunately.

The last two -1 parameters tell PPT to bring the picture in at "natural" size ... ie, whatever size it'd normally insert the image if you did it manually; this avoids distorting the image.

Comment: I mentioned this to one of my Macknowledgeable friends, who tells me that MS disabled this feature as a security risk. Sputter.  Spit.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the path style you are using. The following will work:

```
#If Mac Then
    imagePath = (MacScript("get path to startup disk as string") & "Users:Pedro:My_Picture.png")
#Else
    imagePath = "C:\path\to\My_Picture.png"
#End If

activeSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(imagePath, False, True, 10, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I was looking to add the image directly from the web, which should have worked. I may try a temp download + insertion using your solution in the future. Cheers!

Comment: My pleasure. As Steve mentioned, I don't think direct download works on the Mac. As you have alluded to, I use a temporary download (via Macscript/do shell script/curl) along with this code to insert images from the web into PowerPoint. It actually works very well. Let me know if you'd like me to share that code and I'd be happy to dig it up for you.